# Impossible to load image in jsp?

Tags: java, html, jsp, jakarta-ee

I am having this little problem, I see that it is impossible to load picture in my console, I don't know how to solve the problem.

I am getting my image name from database as a String in my controller, just the name, something like that ' image.jpg' and it is stored in my folder 'images'.

Here is my jsp file :

```
<c:if test="${ !(post.cover == 'empty')}">
   <div class="imgPub">
     <img src="Assets/images/${post.cover }">
   </div>
</c:if>
```

In my inspector i can see the whole src written exactly, but a message next to it saying impossible to load image.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try to load your image directly through it’s url. Problem is not related to Jsp - you say it outputs the image tag, so the problem is that the image can’t be loaded from the url that you use.

Comment: Sorry! load my image throught its url ? i didnt understand that, i am sorry if that sounded stupid from me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HttpServlet** will do the job.

use:

> youraddress.xxx/images/filename.png

this is important @WebServlet("/images/*")

It will automatically leads to folder defined in ***PATH*** and retrieve the image based on the name.

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;

@WebServlet("/images/*")
public class ImageServlet extends HttpServlet {

public static final String PATH = "C:/"
/*
linux
public static final String PATH = "/home/images/"
*/

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String filename = request.getPathInfo().substring(1);
        File file = new File(PATH,filename);
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", getServletContext().getMimeType(filename));
        response.setHeader("Content-Length",String.valueOf(file.length()));
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","inline; filename=\""+filename +"\"");
        Files.copy(file.toPath(),response.getOutputStream());
    }

}
```